# How to merge jpg map tiles to form a bigger map?

Tags: dictionary, jpeg, tiles

I need to merge some jpg map tiles to form a bigger jpg,png,pdf or other formats.

Each jpg map tile has a size of 256px * 256px. There are 384 * 384 tiles.

Please advise the quickest way to merge these map tiles or do you have any other solution that will allow me to combine these map tiles and view them easily?

Please ask for more details if needed.

Comment: you need to utilize your VGA card, the image you want to have is really big, CPU would do it, but it take a while :D

Comment: What software should I use for merging? I plan to browse the map on my computer, so the VGA card shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: I have also thought of merging the jpg tiles to form 4 big files (each having Width: 96 tiles, Height: 384 tiles) so the file size won't go too large.

Comment: you are talking about (256*256)*(384*384) integers, isn't to big? the file size doesn't matter here, the process is more important, you would use OpenCL or CUDA (depending on graphic card family)

Comment: I have an NVIDIA GeForce 9400 GT card. Which do you recommend?

Comment: Hmm, the 9400 GT has 16 cuda cores, not strong enough, but better than nothing, bty, do you have experience with multi-thread (parallel) programming?

Comment: I have very little experience in programming... :(

Comment: I'd rather follow step-by-step instructions..

Comment: Okay, first check this [tutorial here](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html) and get some parallel experience, then try to do your issue (get help of course), later you need to get start with HPC and CUDA. keep in touch for any issue dude :D

Comment: ImageMagick montage will let you set the number of rows and columns of tiles as desired, but the input images must be named alphabetically to match that ordering. However, you may have trouble with the number of characters in your input list of files. That is system dependent. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/. Set -geometry to +0+0 to avoid gaps between tiles.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [How to merge images in command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075087/how-to-merge-images-in-command-line)

My images are 100-001.jpg 100-002.jpg ..... 200-080.jpg
You can then merge horizontal then vertical, (using graphicsMagic or imageMagick)

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {100..200}
do
    gm convert $i-* +append h_$i.jpg
done
gm convert h_* -append all.jpg
```