# iterm2 images not displaying inline

Tags: terminal, ascii, iterm2

iTerm2 has a feature that can be used to display images in the terminal, see https://iterm2.com/documentation-images.html for documentation on the protocol.

I have been able to produce an image in the terminal by using the correct ASCII characters and encoding; this string (starts with ESC and ends with ^G)

```
]1337;File=inline=1: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
```

will produce this output: [image]

however, when I attempt to display another image along side, this happens; string

```
]1337;File=inline=1:iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAAcCAYAAAByDd+UAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAABQtJREFUeNrsVktoXVUUXefc7/vmpUmaNonWSsFYtBZEWhRKERxI60QF6UhBOhAVEXEmzjrVQbXgTBRFB4oTlSq1FEGEiggWlKpVjG0wn9fXvE/u75zjOucmaVIrWhBB6IX9eO9+9tpr7bX3fcIYg//yENcB/33As+PX9oStr8GPvsClJ0dG1AXviIiKSYyJ1+SucFEI3KqXknFZHxpH7n0sW9Xj8UPjEA0Jk2j41wBU5+ejaOnH0NChansLmMjugB+MeDs0REsclGEC4ZHFuEAxPwOVNYfjA5PH5UgAfSnnhX/KUOFZNPWLjFZxxkd6OoKeq0COePCaPkTsQZKaKgCtDALSyM9eBG65+WLlwelZ9Usn5A0xM7X9v5VPYD8m1Ut6VmD5/RrUuRpkVEFwk4RsSRbDsgvhqi9yTVCF0LOPSohMDZtePkyw1YxTPmR+ZVft3SGKMEOEOzFanEw/D5B+2oTwa4h3kVGF/cgJVjDIzDbG1hZ7BkZJELY8f9mQbcZeRubPZY2N6hkPkTGjm0Y7J1AV04N3qshPDyHcWYE/YRvvwRSk4Et4nge9klMbjbzQ8KQpi4ZYn3aYcR/jmP9Jd3KVmtPQaIV+rfnEnu789O435hfUr63Ryt0VWJ1MSiA2SHgEFhLLJBJaYD5qpUyJXvM9mwXrZFxN/irjqB/IjaYxYfyAbuoXsjeX5nC+IaJ9MaSxmnlQTOZZQMnvKwWSEiU08HhLg8gqZ4uMWIezdhxjvEdz1VFGlW0OH1/YfO9bO0/UsGfu583FvuqYVAGWEoEBAYM4RGYkUiaUBK/XAgQBGdl+ybKfQogVHLHOee44xfiMd1nT5BA6fbk7Wj+8+dv58/d8dRrYvQlKhTBkE0ZlYsGkmRbIGT4l7nKQ+xmHmeCSEs4spjynqLq8muffZfTXxqKIw0T01I37Tr4+FGxPkcQTkLS8Zq+qse8YMTea1cAx0dqacEVWUfJoWcYUW+niaoBzjC8doGCzl4Yrvds/PLt1S95HOjUBn89IslIETHODPFeoVUO62NCgJYNGxXPWL2gYwxytGn8XBkl21f18yEpqAR/JqsFv9Zn+/TvPsYgdQxxNgX5hZ0pjqBGUgBouuUfp+knuxqFe8Z073Xmy7A0K5FmOZmyXk7nSOEcYJ32+Lp7rN6O7bvvivGqpZaRDY24XWFdra3eCxmRaZxRORzt0Tk9Y5TxXh3bFkSacZ9cGfgNTO/h7pfLlN1E7w7bZRQ9bIyCBq74SCtQj4QC5ILHUzVg96y4KWCUbvC6UQq+fIUncEnWbxp7XtiD9J1mfsXR9ynl40/cdjA36UDfUWKmhJ4wDEsatdyY2iKxRCu12pKGKqbK95HgovcbEskzygm62U7oBkJscH9ldKgfV8FS8nCDUuZPQVtfp8TtNYte/pG5JkqHTTZicTPLMbmmolIyTFFUm5+Llqyh392v2VOelvG6fXl5tPzBm2HWzf9tPS0eNNE8hZPPZg0bAyr3CDbOdL9uvZcrXFNyVXjkSlbgkVth+uZk3rndxZLePRiapUOQtilpwDgsmWnk9dcSPbx/A9u/ajV7S+VqExQ52plz0q6LYfAQNCJQpg7/+R7JygTdwkvjCzWDioVeqD08/LbfEMINyNv3ts33o0WrX/J4/X1xoHyRMzmrW0ppyrt0rT7On7rcwV+xls3ECjHsuxuLgg/xMG/HUVLn+bDHX/yb+7wH/EGAARjZ2jNWjuZgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=]1337;File=inline=1:iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAAcCAYAAAByDd+UAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAARRJREFUeNpi/P//PwM9AeOohUPfwt83oiOANCcQ/6GxXSxA/B1k4SMgQxCI/9LYQmYgfg+yVZaOIcoDslAV6t1/NLaMCRRtIIvu0DPRgCz8Bk001ATvgFgA6itk8B1kYSgQs1Mp0fwEYikgngvEV4C4AYh/QD0GSjQ/QamUFiH3CYgXAXEOtnwIchUblA8qBR4AsRAQ89PAIb9AXt0NxLxA/BuIVYBYERq8B6E0EykFCTQI30CDUQyq/z+U/gwS9EHTBLI4BIg30iqVTgJibmhqheXJCUDsCXUxExXz4VdQHP7HkqSFaJkPGemd8ZWgND0Kb3DRdpfePrwMzXP0KLw/giwsgmZ8elj4a7QRNWohyQAgwAAQhlmNWgQOSgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==]1337;File=inline=1: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
```

produces [image]

The images are not inline.

How can I ensure consecutive images remain inline? I am able to repeat the result in zsh, and bash. I am on iTerm 2 Build 3.0.4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are two solutions:**

**1>** Insert `\b\33[1A` at the beginning of the second and third image, change the count of `\33[1A` according to the height of image (in your case, it appears once). The meaning of escape sequences can be referenced [here](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php).

```
\e]1337;File=inline=1: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\a\b\33[1A\e]1337;File=inline=1:iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAAcCAYAAAByDd+UAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAARRJREFUeNpi/P//PwM9AeOohUPfwt83oiOANCcQ/6GxXSxA/B1k4SMgQxCI/9LYQmYgfg+yVZaOIcoDslAV6t1/NLaMCRRtIIvu0DPRgCz8Bk001ATvgFgA6itk8B1kYSgQs1Mp0fwEYikgngvEV4C4AYh/QD0GSjQ/QamUFiH3CYgXAXEOtnwIchUblA8qBR4AsRAQ89PAIb9AXt0NxLxA/BuIVYBYERq8B6E0EykFCTQI30CDUQyq/z+U/gwS9EHTBLI4BIg30iqVTgJibmhqheXJCUDsCXUxExXz4VdQHP7HkqSFaJkPGemd8ZWgND0Kb3DRdpfePrwMzXP0KLw/giwsgmZ8elj4a7QRNWohyQAgwAAQhlmNWgQOSgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==\a\b\33[1A\e]1337;File=inline=1: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\a
```

[image]

The text I pasted above is the content of file `/tmp/three`

**2>** Merge the images use ImageMagick, which you can reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075087/how-to-merge-images-in-linux-command-line).

[image]

Please let me know if these two solutions can't solve your problem properly.